# When are C# Draw/Fill functions called? How can they be invoked from a separate class?

Tags: c#, system.drawing, paintevent

**I'm not sure of how the Paint form lifecycle works, when is the `Form1_Paint` function called? How can I control when it's called?**

I know I can call Draw a Circle using the C# Drawing library like so:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(1, 1, 1, 1));
}
```

If I define an object like so:

```
class myCircleObject
{
    int x, y, radius;

    public myCircleObject(int x_val, int y_val, int r)
    {
        x = x_val;
        y = y_val;
        radius = r;
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle r = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, radius, radius);
        //Draw Circle here
    }
}
```

or if I can't do that **how can I call the `Form1_Paint` function as opposed to it just running immediately at run time**.

Comment: It's not clear [what problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) you are having. The `Paint` event is a part of the form lifecycle and it must be handled there and then, using the provided `Graphics` object, anything else would simply not make sense. If you want to use your class in handling the `Paint` event, one option would be to pass the `PaintEventArgs e` into its `Draw` method. If you simply want to draw something somewhere regardless of the form lifecycle, create a `Graphics` object yourself from inside your class.

Comment: Add a parameter to your function: *public void Draw(Graphics thegraphics)*, then *thegraphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red,r)*

Comment: I have no idea which pixels you want to color..?? Or why you don't want to use the Paint event..??

Comment: @GSerg I suppose I don't understand the form lifecycle so I'm not sure of when it gets called. That's why, instead of asking an XY problem, I show this is how I get something to draw, I want to know how to control when it gets drawn as opposed to seemingly **immediately at runtime**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

- The typical way is to paint asynchronously. Call [`Invalidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) on whatever form/control has your custom drawing logic. The framework will raise the `Paint` event method at the appropriate time.
- A more forceful (non-recommended) way is to paint synchronously. Call [`Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) on your form/control, which will cause it to raise `Paint` immediately.

For example (this is not complete, but it illustrates the concept):

```
public class Form1
{
    private MyCircle _circle;

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       _circle.Draw(e); // this line causes the Circle object to draw itself on Form1's surface
    }

    public void MoveTheCircle(int xOffset, int yOffset)
    {
        _circle.X += xOffset; // make some changes that cause the circle to be rendered differently
        _circle.Y += yOffset;
        this.Invalidate(); // this line tells Form1 to repaint itself whenever it can
    }
}
```

Comment: If I felt I understand the question I'd say: This is exactly what he doesn't want. But I really have no idea..

Comment: I think this _is_ what OP wants. It looks like OP is trying to move drawing code out of the Paint event handler into classes that each handle drawing of a specific type of artifact. I'm sure OP knows how and when to update his circle's properties, but he doesn't know how to cause the repaint to happen after doing so.

Comment: @MichaelGunter this is what I'm looking for the only question i have is what would you put in the `MyCircle.Draw` function. Would it be `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(1, 1, 1, 1));`? I also edited the question in an attempt to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, you would use something like that. Your circle has attributes of it's own (`x`, `y`, `radius`), so you would use those instead of `1, 1, 1, 1`. I imagine it would be something like `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, this.x, this.y, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);`